# How do i disable W button on keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, playonlinux, ubuntu-tweak

My laptop has some problem in W button due to which i am unable to work properly.
Is there anyway to disable W button ?
I have tried xmodmap but its not working now.

Comment: Possibly `xmodmap -e 'keycode 22='`. This should map keycode 25 (keysym 0x77) "w" to null.

Comment: Tried but not its not working on latest Ubuntu model

Comment: @doneal24 In my installation, 22 is for Backspace.

Answer (score 1):

Install [x11-utils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/x11-utils)

```
sudo apt install x11-utils
```

Identify keycode

```
xev | grep keycode
```

Press <kbd>w</kbd> key. You'll see the keycode. Assign empty value to the observed keycode.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode here-your-keycode='
```

If you want to undo the action, run

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode here-your-keycode=w'
```

It's always good to save the current setting. To do so, run

```
xmodmap -pke > /path/to/file
```